# Text fields stop working with AngularJs Model

Tags: html, angularjs

this text field stops working when I add an ng-model:

```
<input type="time" value="23:20:50.52" />
```

Why would this happen, and how can I have an ng-model in a time field with a preset value?

Answer (score 0):

Refer : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D

> > the text must be entered in a valid ISO-8601 local time format (HH:mm:ss), for example: 14:57:00.
> >
> > Model must be a Date object

ex :

```
<script>
 angular.module('timeExample', [])
   .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.example = {
       value: new Date(1970, 0, 1, 14, 57, 0)
     };
   }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
 <input type="time" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value" />
</form>
```

Comment: The issue is being able to submit the form fields, but having an entry in them that was the original data.  So a person clicks edit and the original form values are in the form for them to change.

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of needing to assign an ng-model to the tag? Just so you can specify a value in the controller? If that's the case you should just set the value to the angular scope variable and define the value in the controller. The tag would be:

```
<input type="time" value="{{currentTime}}" />
```

And in the controller you would have:

```
$scope.currentTime = "23:20:50.52";
```